# How to modularise reactive output in Shiny (that includes if statement)?

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny

Up until recently, I had been repeating the same reactive statements within each output of the server object.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 output$MeanResult <- renderText({
   if(input$Posi != "All"){
     ProjDt <- ProjDt[ProjDt$Pos == input$Posi,]
   }
   ProjDt <- filter(ProjDt, TimeToKO < input$TimeKO)
   mean(ProjDt[[input$Metric]])
 })
 output$hist <- renderPlot({
   if(input$Posi != "All"){
     ProjDt <- ProjDt[ProjDt$Pos == input$Posi,]
   }
   ProjDt <- filter(ProjDt, TimeToKO < input$TimeKO)
   hist(ProjDt[[input$Metric]])
 })
}
```

This seems to produce the desired result but I would like to avoid duplicating the reactive part of each output.

I therefore attempted to 'modularise' the reactive part of the code before passing it to the output statements such that:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 ProjDt <- reactive({
   if(input$Posi != "All"){
      ProjDt <- ProjDt[ProjDt$Pos == input$Posi,]
   }
   ProjDt <- filter(ProjDt, TimeToKO < input$TimeKO)
   ProjDt <- ProjDt[[input$Metric]]
 })
 output$MeanResult <- renderText({
   mean(ProjDt())
 })
 output$hist <- renderPlot({
   hist(ProjDt())
 })
}
```

I've played around with it quite a lot but I can't get the desired result. The main error I get is that `'object of type 'closure' is not subsettable'`.

I'm relatively new to Shiny so I feel like I'm missing something quite fundamental.

What do I need to do get the modularised reactive output to work?

Comment: Can you try use a different name for the result of the reactive than the name inside the reactive (you used `ProjDt` for both right now)

Comment: Wow @warmoverflow that seemed to work. I'll show myself to the door :)